Angular: Data path "" must have required property 'buildTarget'
Following on from this post
I am trying to "undo" swapping to the new Angular es-build, as perhaps Ionic does not like it.
So, my angular.json now looks very similar to a new default Ionic/Angular project I created.
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath":"www",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [              
              "semaphore-async-await",
              "chart.js",
              "chartjs-plugin-datalabels"
            ],
            "preserveSymlinks": true,            
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",            
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.min.css",
                "output": "assets/theme",
                "input": "./node_modules/@bryntum/scheduler/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "output": "assets/theme/fonts",
                "input": "./node_modules/@bryntum/scheduler/fonts"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],
            "styles": ["src/global.scss", "src/theme/variables.scss"],
            "scripts": [],
            "aot": false,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true            
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "30mb",
                  "maximumError": "35mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production-win": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.win.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "30mb",
                  "maximumError": "35mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production-win-dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.win.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "30mb",
                  "maximumError": "35mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",          
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "app:build:production"
            },
            "production-win": {
              "buildTarget": "app:build:production"
            },
            "production-win-dev": {
              "buildTarget": "app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "app:build:development"
            },
            "ci": {}
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src/",
                "output": "/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              }
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "ci": {
              "progress": false,
              "watch": false
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-build": {
          "builder": "@ionic/cordova-builders:cordova-build",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-serve": {
          "builder": "@ionic/cordova-builders:cordova-serve",
          "options": {
            "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build:production",
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "app-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "ci": {
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:ci"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@ionic/angular-toolkit"
    ],
    "analytics": "766e20ce-9036-4dcc-a0cc-d82d67688f03"
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}

But now when I ng serve I get
    SchemaValidationException [Error]: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
[ng]   Data path "" must have required property 'buildTarget'.
[ng]   Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'.
[ng]   Data path "" must match a schema in anyOf.
[ng]     at C:\dev\my-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:40:27 {
[ng]   errors: [
[ng]     {
[ng]       instancePath: '',
[ng]       schemaPath: '#/anyOf/0/required',
[ng]       keyword: 'required',
[ng]       params: { missingProperty: 'buildTarget' },
[ng]       message: "must have required property 'buildTarget'"
[ng]     },
[ng]     {
[ng]       instancePath: '',
[ng]       schemaPath: '#/anyOf/1/required',
[ng]       keyword: 'required',
[ng]       params: { missingProperty: 'browserTarget' },
[ng]       message: "must have required property 'browserTarget'"
[ng]     },
[ng]       message: "must have required property 'browserTarget'"
[ng]     },
[ng]     {
[ng]     {
[ng]       instancePath: '',
[ng]       schemaPath: '#/anyOf',
[ng]       keyword: 'anyOf',
[ng]       params: {},
[ng]       message: 'must match a schema in anyOf'
[ng]     }
[ng]   ]
[ng] }
[ng] Node.js v20.15.1

I am guessing it is something in the architect tag, but looking in architect.js I cannot work out what the above is talking about. I am not sure how to debug into it.
What is wrong with my angular.json?

The best way is to revert the commit or discard changes, if you are using git.

Create a new ionic project with the same version as your project.
Then compare the architect.js with your file.
See where the props buildTarget and browserTarget are present. Fix this hopefully it solves this issue!
